# How can I increase the base-emitter voltage of an NPN transistor in forward active region?

Tags: transistors, bjt, npn

For a project which involves amplification, I think I have to increase the base voltage, keeping the emitter voltage the same so that my circuit will not go out of forward active region as the amplitude of my input signal is higher than usual like 5 V.

I know that when an NPN is biased in the forward active region, the voltage between base and emitter is like 0.7 V which is the turn on voltage, but I need to make it like, let's say, 2 V.

Is there any way to do that?

The reason I am asking is that output to base of BJT is so much and base voltage cannot be higher than emitter voltage at all times which is concerning and I would resolve this.

The circuit with beta = 300

[image: colpitts oscillator]

Comment: A BJT doesn't have a turn-on voltage of 700 mV. It is active with 300 mV or 400 mV or 500 mV, too. The deal is more like *"for every 60 mV increase, there is a 10-fold increase in collector current."* So if it is 3 mA at 700 mV then it is 300 uA at 640 mV and 30 uA at 580 mV and 3 uA at 520 mV. Likewise, it is 30 mA at 760 mV and 300 mA at 820 mV.

Comment: @jonk can't I add voltage source at base. I cannot increase collector current more than 3mA

Comment: @OnurTR In general, you want the collector current to vary by less than a factor of 10. So if you cannot accept more than 3 mA, then your bottom end will be about 300 uA and you'll want a quiescent current of about 950 uA. (Call it 1 mA.) You haven't mentioned what kind of voltage gain is required and you've not discussed any details about the signal source. Etc. There's little that can be said to help you, I fear.

Comment: @jonk I added circuit I am trying to implement a colpitts oscillator and output of this is clipped from bottom and when I look at collector and base voltages, they are as they should be(collector is higher than base voltage at all times), but emiiter voltage is not lower than base voltage. The gain must be about -4 to keep oscillation going

Comment: @jonk what about a voltage divider added right after C1 to make input to BJT smaller?

Comment: Where is the input and where is the output?

Comment: @mkeith right of C4 is output, input is left of C1

Comment: Why not use some sort of feedback from output to input?

Comment: @nanofarad I do not understand

Comment: @OnurTR That's more like a Pierce, isn't it? (Didn't recognize it, at first.)

Comment: @jonk I decided to remove C5 and increased input resistance R2//R3, then gain is like -4. I hope it works. I do not know what Pierce is.

Comment: @OnurTR I suspect your biasing is too stiff and that C1 is way too large. I'd also put a series resistor with C5.

Comment: Of course it will clip and the output will be distorted -- in a feedback oscillator like this, you need to limit the gain as the output grows. The transistor will have some portion of the cycle with B > E, but it is possible (because of C3) that the average emitter V is > average base V

Comment: @jp314 should feedback fraction be smaller? you say . I mean C2/C3. In other words should I increase C3

Comment: @jp314 I think if I place a capacitor at base, it would decrease coupled voltage coming from feedback and I would receive a better result. What do you say

Comment: @OnurTR I just threw [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NT7t.png) into LTspice without thinking much. 1 MHz, approximately, using a not-so-special BJT.

Comment: Can you precisely explain what problem you are trying to solve without guessing at solutions. If it's clipping that is the problem then maybe I can direct you.

Comment: Experienced electronic designers never use transistor's beta. It depends on temperature and other things. They use circuit stages that don't depend on Beta.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to control ratio of voltage base-emitter and emitter-collector.

You can do it by changing ratio of C2 to C3, keeping the total the same.

If you want higher voltage output of the circuit, you need to make C3 smaller and C2 larger. This will also make startup and stability worse though.

I want to add that such circuits in general are probably not a good start. They can completely change behaviour somewhere else when something is changed.